# co-relation values based on column & row values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
Prs 10  20  30  40  50
5   40  40  40  40  40
10  100 100 100 100 100
15  150 150 150 150 150
25  256 256 260 264 268
40  291 291 293 296 300
```

First column is the `pressure` and rest of the columns are `temperature`. The values in the tables are `speed'.
The ways we read this table is for a pressure of 5 & a temperature of 10, speed is 40. Similarly,for a pressure of 25 & a temperature of 40, the speed is 264.

However, i want to know how i can get the speed for a pressure & temperature that are not explicitly in the table but inside the range mentioned in the table. For example what would be the speed for pressure 12.6 & temprature 21.2? How do i do that?
I can try & extrapolate the pressure column with intervals of 0.1 and the temperature also by 0.1 and then fill the values, but that makes this table too cumbersome & complex.

Is there any other way to do it? does co-relation function of Pandas come-in handy here? please guide.
**Note:** In the complete table some time the speed decreases as well between intervals for example . For example when prs=90 & temp=75, the speed is 515, but when prs=90 & temp=85, speed is 480.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a 2D interpolation. Neither Pandas nor numpy alone after methods for that. If it is worth it, you can install the full scipy package and then use `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`:

```
val = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(df['Prs'].values, df.columns[1:].astype('int').value,
                                 df.iloc[:, 1:].values)(12.6, 21.2)
```

This would use a linear interpolation, but scipy provides for various spline methods, just look at the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

---

If installing the full scipy is not an option, you can first interpolate the columns *by hand* at the pressure value and then interpolate the resulting array at the temp value:

```
def interp(x,y):
    it = [np.interp(x, df['Prs'], df.iloc[:, i]) for i in range(1, len(df.columns))]
    return np.interp(y, df.columns[1:].astype('float'), it)


interp(12.6, 21.2)
```

returns as expected 126.0

Comment: i did the following `from scipy import interpolate` `val = interpolate.interp2d(sp_accpd['accped'].values, sp_accpd.columns[1:].astype('int').values,
                                 sp_accpd.iloc[:, 1:].values)(12.6, 21.2)` but i get the error as below `ValueError: When on a regular grid with x.size = m and y.size = n, if z.ndim == 2, then z must have shape (n, m)`

Comment: Note in the code i used , i changed from "value" to "values" in this line `sp_accpd.columns[1:].astype('int').values`

Comment: The function that you provided (`interp(x,y)`) works perfectly though.